# Magento 2 Sales Order Items in Custom Email

Tags: magento2.4.6

I have created custom email template and calling order item in it. In my site I'm adding or editing the specific order Item and I need need to send email for that item only. It was working fine in the Magento 2.4.3. Now I have upgraded to 2.4.6-p1 and it's giving error when going to send the email.

**sales_email_order_custom_items.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" label="Email Order Items List" design_abstraction="custom">
<update handle="sales_email_order_renderers"/>
<update handle="sales_email_item_price"/>
<body>
    <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Email\Items" name="items" template="Vendor_Module::email/added_items.phtml" cacheable="false">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\RendererList" name="sales.email.order.renderers" as="renderer.list"/>
    </block>
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="additional.product.info" template="Magento_Theme::template.phtml"/>
</body>
```

**Send Email:**

```
$templateOptions = [
    'area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND,
    'store' =>  $this->storeManager->getStore($order->getStoreId())->getId()
];

$templateVars = [
      'store' => $store,
      'order'=> $order,
      'item' => $this->orderItemRepository->get($itemId),
      'action' => $itemAction
];

$transport = $this->transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier($emailtemplate)
            ->setTemplateOptions($templateOptions)
            ->setTemplateVars($templateVars)
            ->setFrom($senderInfo)
            ->addTo($ccEmails, $receiverInfo['name'])
            ->getTransport();
```

**Error: Call to a member function getStoreId() on null in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-tax/Block/Item/Price/Renderer.php:82**

```
/**
 * Set item for render
 *
 * @param QuoteItem|OrderItem|InvoiceItem|CreditMemoItem $item
 * @return $this
 */
public function setItem($item)
{
    $this->item = $item;
    $this->storeId = $item->getStoreId();
    return $this;
}
```

**Email Template:**

```
<?php
$item = $block->getItem();
?>
<table class="email-items">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="item-info">
                <?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Image')) ?>
            </th>
            <th class="item-info">
                <?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Item')) ?>
            </th>
            <th class="item-info">
                <?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Sku')) ?>
            </th>
            <th class="item-qty">
                <?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Qty')) ?>
            </th>
            <th class="item-price">
                <?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Price')) ?>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
        <?php if (!$item->getParentItemId()) : ?>
            <tbody>
                <?= $block->getItemHtml($item) ?>
            </tbody>
        <?php endif; ?>
</table>
```